# Android Copy Paste: Special character being copied to clipboard before link text

Tags: android, clipboard

I have implemented copy paste on a textview in my app. Textview have html which are set using Html.fromHtml

However, I noticed that if you copy multiline HTML where a line starts with a link (`<a>` tag), it prepends a special character [OBJ] before it.

For eg. We copy

> First line
>
> [Link](http://google.com) on second line

On pasting this into a simple edittext, it shows as

> First line
>
> [OBJ]Link on second line

Is there a way to prevent this from being copied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured that the issue was because there was an < img > tag in the textview (Html.fromHtml used to add html to it)

The [OBJ] character was due to this img.

The only way to remove it was doing a replace of the special char with char code 65532